# How can I implement this plan in c# to read all data and write another table?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have two tables in SQL Server:

- Table 1 with columns `name`, `family`, `address`
- Table 2 with columns `name`, `family`

And my server properties is this:

- RAM: 64GB
- Intel 24 core xeon

Im the table 1 may be have 30 million, and I want read all data that, and just insert name and family from table 1 to table 2. I'm using Linq-to-SQL, but that is slow, how can I implement that scenario rapidly in C#? Thanks.

Comment: why do you need C#? That could be done with just sql server code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can execute the following query on the server:

```
 INSERT INTO table2
 SELECT Name, Family
   FROM table1
```

That will copy all the records from `table1` into `table2` directly on the SQL Server.

Of course, if you must do it from C#, you can execute the same query using a SQLCommand.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    String query = @"INSERT INTO table2
                       SELECT Name, Family
                         FROM table1";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
    command.Connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

If you need to do some processing to the data in C# a good option is to use the [SqlBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class but it's going to take a bit more work to set up the operation.

Comment: i run that but i get this error:Additional information: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Answer (score 0):

You can using following code:

```
         // db = DataContext
         var toInsert = from t1 in db.Table1
           where ...
           select new Table2
           {
               name = b.name,
               family = b.family
           };
        db.Table2.InsertAllOnSubmit(toInsert);
        db.SubmitChanges();
```